# Spring Boot Junit test injecting dao interface with constructor injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Okay So I am trying to set up a springboot/junit test that tests a DAO that is injected to other classes via constructor injection.
Initially I tried constructor injection

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDao;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class ProjectDaoTest  {

    ProjectDao projectDao;

    @Test
    public void getProject() {
        assert projectDao.getProjectById(1L) != null;
    }

    public ProjectDaoTest() {}

    public ProjectDaoTest(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }

    public void setProjectDao(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }
}
```

but then get the error message

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Test class can only have one constructor
```

So then looked around and saw some options which boiled down to either using Junit 5(allows multiple constructors) or using Mockito to . 
I would prefer to stick to whats in the spring-starter-test package. So I went with the mockito route. as such

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
// import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDao;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)

public class ProjectDaoTest  {

    @InjectMocks ProjectDao projectDao;

    @Test
    public void getProject() {
        assert projectDao.getProjectById(1L) != null;

    }

    public ProjectDaoTest() {}

    public void setProjectDao(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }
}
```

But came across this issue,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 

Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'projectDao'! Cause: the type 'ProjectDao' is an interface.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
Examples of correct usage of @InjectMocks:
@InjectMocks Service service = new Service();
@InjectMocks Service service;
//and... don't forget about some @Mocks for injection :)
```

If I try to mock the DAO implementation (which I am trying to avoid), I get an error

```
@InjectMocks ProjectDaoImpl projectDao;

// error
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.portfolio.bork.webapp.daotest.ProjectDaoTest.getProject(ProjectDaoTest.java:23)
```

Here is my DAO interface

```
public interface ProjectDao {
    public Project getProjectById(Long projectId);
}
```

its implementation

```
package com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import com.portfolio.bork.webapp.model.Project;

@Repository
public class ProjectDaoImpl implements ProjectDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public ProjectDaoImpl() {}

    public Project getProjectById(Long projectId) {
        return entityManager.find(Project.class, projectId);
    }
}
```

I utilize them as such in my Rest Controller

```
@RestController
public class ProjectRestController {

    private ProjectDao projectDao;

    ...

    // for constructor injection
    public ProjectRestController(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }

    public void setProjectDao(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }

}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.portfolio.bork</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
    <version>01</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webapp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Im somewhat new to different forms of dependency injection(other than autowiring fields) in Spring Boot, and new to unit testing as well.
And am using this application to poke with how Test code interacts with dependency injection, the source code and the test applicationContext.
I also would like to be able to not refer to the Dao Implementation code in the Test code.

Update: 
If I try to autowire the setter, I get this error. I think my test is not picking up the source code application context?

```
package com.portfolio.bork.webapp;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

// import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDao;
import com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDaoImpl;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)

public class ProjectDaoTest  {

    ProjectDao projectDao;

    @Test
    public void getProject() {
        assert projectDao.getProjectById(1L) != null;

    }

    public ProjectDaoTest() {}

    @Autowired
    public void setProjectDao(ProjectDao projectDao) {
        this.projectDao = projectDao;
    }
}



2020-04-20 19:16:12.256 ERROR 21124 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@68567e20] to prepare test instance [com.portfolio.bork.webapp.ProjectDaoTest@593aaf41]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.portfolio.bork.webapp.ProjectDaoTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through 
method 'setProjectDao' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:723) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40) [junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71) ~[junit-vintage-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.portfolio.bork.webapp.services.db.ProjectDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:715) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try using just `@Mock` instead of `@InjectMocks`

Comment: I tried that but then get Unresolved compilation problem: 
        Mock cannot be resolved to a type

        at com.portfolio.bork.webapp.daotest.ProjectDaoTest.<init>(ProjectDaoTest.java:19)

Comment: what was the error? Did you import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Auto-configured Data JPA Tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

> You can use the @DataJpaTest annotation to test JPA applications. By default, it scans for @Entity classes and configures Spring Data JPA repositories. If an embedded database is available on the classpath, it configures one as well. Regular @Component beans are not loaded into the ApplicationContext.

Your repository in NOT a Spring Data repository, and hence is not loaded to the context

IMHO using a Spring Data repo (with custom methods if needed) is the way to go in your case.

See also: [Unable to test custom repositories using Spring Boot Test #8501](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8501)